# php date is wrong?

Tags: php

Let's say I have this:

```
$a11 = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $a['date']); 
$newTime = date($a['date'], strtotime('+3 hour'));
$b11 = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $newTime); 
echo $a11 . " AND " . $b11;
```

I know $a['date'] is right because I get: `March 22, 2011, 10:22 pm`. However, the echo produces: `March 22, 2011, 10:22 pm AND March 22, 2011, 10:22 pm` when clearly the second part is suppose to be three hours ahead.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try 'hours', instead of 'hour'

Comment: the s-suffix in 'hours' can be supplied, but will make no difference(it will be ignored). See http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#SEC125

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you want:

```
$newTime = strtotime( '+3 hours',$a['date'] );
$b11 = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $newTime );
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you provide the wrong order of parameters in `$newTime = date($a['date'], strtotime('+3 hour'));`. Try this:

```
<?php
$a['date'] = mktime();
$a11 = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $a['date']); 
$newTime = date(strtotime('+3 hour'),$a['date']);
$b11 = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $newTime); 
echo $a11 . " AND " . $b11;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dig it, you are not strtotime'ing the $newTime when converting to date, so it's false.

```
<?php
$a['date'] = time();

$a11 = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $a['date']);

echo 'Now       = ' . time() . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Now +3hrs = ' . strtotime( '+3 hours' ) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$newTime = strtotime( '+3 hours' );

$b11 = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $newTime );

echo $a11 . ' and ' . $b11 . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of `date` function is: `string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp ] )`. So, according to the first line, `$a['date']` stores the timestamp value. But, according to the second line, its value is date format.

Moreover, you should type "+3 hours".

Answer (score 0):

I add date like following

```
<?php
$a['date']="March 22, 2011, 10:22 pm";
$a11 = date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($a['date'])); 
$b11 = strtotime(date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($a['date'])) . " +3 hours");
$b11 = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $b11); 
echo $a11 . "AND " . $b11;
?>
```